# Can 'very' mean 'exact/precise'?

Tags: word-usage

There's a part of a dialogue in a movie I saw:

> If the patient who killed herself in this room, in this **very** tub, is
> here now, make yourself known.

I've looked up the definition of *very* (adjective) in Oxford dictionary; it's used to emphasize a noun. Is it possibly the other way to say the exact/precise place that the speaker's talking about?

For example, the word very, am I using it correctly in these sentences below?:

1. She sat in this very chair last night.
2. I will sleep on this very bed.
3. There was a man standing on this very bench.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From wiktionary

> [**very, adj.**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/very#English)
> The same; identical.
> *He proposed marriage in the same restaurant, at the **very** table where they first met.*

Your examples are all acceptable usage.

Comment: The emphatic nature of "very" means that, in the examples given, the speaker thinks that the particular identity of the chair, bed, bench is surprising.  The speaker expects the listener to think "Oooh! *This* chair!? I didn't know that."

Comment: The word very used to mean true, real, actual. This meaning survives in these examples.